# Is C++11 type_traits based condition block eliminated after compilation?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to understand C++11's type_traits. From what I understand it enables compile-time type determination. So I want to know what will happen in the following case:

Say I have a simple templated class:

```
template<class T>
class A {
    public:
        int num = 0;
        A() {
           if (is_integral<T>::value)
                num = 5;
        }
}
```

Now say I am instantiating `A<int> a` a 100 times, does that mean that for every construction of the object, the if block is called in the constructor? Or does the compiler eliminate (optimize away) the if-block during compilation? Do ask me if I should clarify my question further.

Comment: It would resolve to `if(true)` so it is likely the compiler would optimize that away. But that has nothing to do with `type_traits` itself.

Comment: Moreover, the compiler should issue a warning like "expression is alwasy true" if all warnings enabled.

Comment: @juanchopanza I didn't understand what you meant when you said it has nothing to do with `type_traits`. After all `type_traits` provides `is_integral`, right?

Comment: I mean you could have any compile time constant inside the `if`, and it would get optimized out.

Comment: beware that, say you get false, this does not eliminate the code branch with regard to the compiler, so unfortunately the code must still be correct inside the block. That's a very sad thing that forces people to use SFINAE and sub-functions to switch to code blocks that cannot compile in case of type T or type U, .... for the runtime though yeah it's eliminated.

Answer (score 1):

> Or does the compiler eliminate (optimize away) the if-block during
>   compilation?

Yes, `is_integral` is a template class, and `value` is a public static member constant of that class. The compiler can (and will, at least if you turn on optimization) easily eliminate if statements using constants.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral

Answer (score 1):

The `if` gets a constant value. After template instantiation, it becomes `if ( false )`. Whether the instructions for `n = 5` are omitted from the application binary is implementation-defined. Certainly with any optimization enabled, dead code will be eliminated, but the compiler is allowed to leave it there, for debugging or through laziness.

Calling the `if ( false )` means doing nothing, so yes, nothing is certainly what happens. Optimization generally doesn't change the behavior of a program. It's also a safe bet that it will happen in zero cycles. The compiler won't load zero into a register and then test it, probably even in debugging mode, because that would be fairly contrived.

Comment: Don't you mean "after template instantiation, it becomes `if (true)`?" Am i missing something?

Comment: Oh, yeah. So the `if` itself takes no time but the assignment inside it might use real CPU instructions.